# Wordpress doesn't show CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, apache2

newbie here trying to make a webserver on my raspberry Pi. I managed to properly set everything except for the CSS part. As you can see from the image, whenever I'm trying to access the home page, it looks way too basic unlike what the tutorials show. Additionally, I tried every possible solution that was available such as configuring the .conf file, reinstalling packages, updating, changing permission levels, removing index.html, and restarting apache2. I would appreciate if someone can verify if my thought process of the problem is correct or I'm missing the main point of the situation. Any additional troubleshooting steps would be highly appreciated too!

Cheers!

[image: Home Page of Wordpress]

Comment: I can assure you, PHP is working in your case. What is most likely missing is CSS, and possibly the correct URL in the Wordpress Database.

Comment: I also think php works for you and this image shows this.
So check if your styles are called or not if it uses default templates.
Try this too. Go to the Permalinks section and set the settings to the default and save

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've done some research and yes, CSS is definitely the issue here. I've tried setting the permalinks but that too failed. Would you mind further elaborating on the first suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the PHP is working on your end but the static files aren't responding properly. Most often, the issue occurs due to not setting up the MIME Types properly. Make sure that the CSS and JS filetypes are included in the **MIME Type** configuration(available on the apache configuration file), in the following way-

**AddType application/x-javascript .js**

**AddType text/css .css**

If that doesn't solve the issue, Kindly attach a screenshot of the configuration file with your question. That will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your input I added in the line of code into the mime.types but it still doesn't solve the issue. As for the file screenshot it is way over 100 line of codes and I couldn't provide a screenshot of it. Sorry

Comment: @hardstuckprogrammer , is there any error getting logged on the console? You can share that error log if possible.